# SOLR issue - too many search queries

Tags: performance, solr

We have a PHP web application which is using SOLR for searching. The APP is using CURL to connect to the SOLR server and which run in a loop with thousands of predefined keywords. That will create thousands of different search quires to SOLR at a given time.

My issue is that, when a single user logged into the app everything is working as expected. When there is more than one user is trying to run the app we are getting this response from the server.

> Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Cannot assign requested
>   addressFailed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Cannot assign requested
>   addressFailed

Our assumption is that, SOLR server is unable to handle this much search queries at a given time. If so what is the solution to overcome this?. Is there any settings like keep-alive in SOLR?

Any help would be highly appreciate.

Thanks,

Arun S

Comment: each user request generates thousand requests to SOLR ? You'll need quite a high scalability in order to provide such a service

Comment: Please also explain why you need to run a thousand queries in succession for a single user's request? You may have to redesign your application. In the meantime, make your program sleep 75 milliseconds (silly rule of thumb!) between requests to mitigate random failures (if that is what you are having).

Comment: Agreed with the above. If the keywords are predefined and there are a lot of them, then it would be a good idea to do the loop as a scheduled task (say, once per day) and save the results somewhere.

Comment: Posted on the solr user mailing list too: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/SOLR-issue-too-many-search-queries-tt3899518.html

Comment: @aitchnyu Each user has a predefined keyword dictionary which contains 500 or more keywords. Suppose we have 500 keywords and 10 users then we have total 500X10 search queries to SOLR. We can't add sleep as it will slow the App. Is there any Maximum connection limit in SOLR?.Is there any way to improve performance of SOLR server.?

Answer (score 0):

What about OR'ing a subset of the keywords and do just one query?
Then, if nothing was found, try with the next subset of keywords?

For this particular case I think you need to improve your application performance, not SOLR's, even if you need to do some trickery.

> Is there any Maximum connection limit in SOLR?

This is heavily dependent on the hardware and operating system you are using, and probably which servlet container you use.

If you need more performance out of SOLR, you may need to tweak your schema (which you could post here for more help), sale vertically (ram directories or SSD's) or considering a master-slave setup.